# Remote HLS file (stream.m3u8) over nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, nginx-reverse-proxy, enigma2

I would like to run a remote HLS file (stream.m3u8) via a reverse proxy (nginx).

Example: 
My Dreambox has a streaming server which broadcasts the stream via http://192.168.1.110:8080/stream.m3u8.

This works wonderfully in the home network. Now I would like to access this stream via a domain from outside without opening port 8080 in the router.

https://www.example.com => http://192.168.1.110:8080/stream.m3u8

So how can I configure this reverse proxy in Nginx? Would be grateful for any answer

Regards